# Convert string with comma to integer

Tags: ruby, integer, data-conversion

Is there any neat method to convert "1,112" to integer 1112, instead of 1?

I've got one, but not neat:

```
"1,112".split(',').join.to_i #=> 1112
```

Answer (score 183, accepted):

How about this?

```
 "1,112".delete(',').to_i
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's way much better than mine. In fact i was hoping there would be one call instead of two. like: "1,112".to_money. After reviewing the answers, it's likely there's no such method. Anyway, thanks so much!

Comment: @michealKohi can you tell me Why delete() is much faster than doing the same in gsub which accepts regex, I have always thought regex way is faster. I have ran Benchmark on both on its a huge difference in execution time.

Comment: @Abhinay Regarding your bench marks: sample size? String size?

Answer (score 6):

You may also want to make sure that your code localizes correctly, or make sure the users are used to the "international" notation. For example, "1,112" actually means different numbers across different countries. In Germany it means the number a little over one, instead of one thousand and something.

Corresponding Wikipedia article is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark. It seems to be poorly written at this time though. For example as a Chinese I'm not sure where does these description about thousand separator in China come from.

Answer (score 4):

Some more convenient

```
"1,1200.00".gsub(/[^0-9]/,'')
```

it makes "1 200 200" work properly aswell

Comment: Even better is `'1,1200.00'.gsub(/[^0-9\.]/,'').to_f`.

Comment: Wait, why would you want to convert `"1,1200.00"` to `"1120000"`? Don't you just want to replace the `,` (or, depending on the locale, the `.`)? Also, this doesn't convert it to an integer or float, just a string without delimiters.

Comment: @Bryan: To venture a guess, you might want to do this in a banking application, when converting a currency amount that the user has input, in order to deal with only integers inside the application: for instance, converting dollars and cents to cents. This method will avoid any rounding errors that might crop up unexpectedly when dealing with floating-point numbers. When a currency amount needs to be shown to the user, the cent amount can be converted to dollars and cents. (Though that is not what the questioner asked about.)

Comment: This answer doesn't even address the asker's request to convert the string to an integer or float.

Answer (score 2):

The following is another method that will work, although as with some of the other methods it will strip decimal places.

```
a = 1,112
b = a.scan(/\d+/).join().to_i => 1112
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do using [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-tr) :

```
"1,112".tr(',','').to_i # => 1112
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking to sub out more than a comma I'm a fan of:

```
"1,200".chars.grep(/\d/).join.to_i
```

dunno about performance but, it is more flexible than a `gsub`, ie:

```
"1-200".chars.grep(/\d/).join.to_i
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String count = count.replace(",", "");
```