# Why can't I append to the end of an array recursively in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion, types, primitive-types

I'm brand new to ruby and I've run into an error that I haven't been able to find the answer to in google, or stack overflow.

I'm trying to put the first 10 values of the fibinachi sequence into an array like so:

```
#@fib=[] #Maybe try creating the array differently?
@fib=Array.new
foo=42
puts "foo is of type #{foo.class}"
@fib.push(42) #Testing the array

puts @fib #Show the test

def find_fib(anumber)
    return anumber if anumber <= 1
    ( find_fib(anumber - 1) + find_fib(anumber - 2 ))
    #@fib.push(anumber.to_i) #Maybe I need to specify it is an integer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466988/ruby-convert-string-to-integer-or-float
    puts "anumber is of type #{anumber.class}"
    puts "They array is of type #{@fib.class}"
    puts "a number is #{anumber}"
    @fib.push(anumber) #<= this line fails
end

puts find_fib(10)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
...`+': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array (TypeError)
.......
foo is of type Fixnum
42
anumber is of type Fixnum
They array is of type Array
a number is 2
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

Can someone explain to me what is different between `foo` and `anumber` that prevents me from appending to the array? After all, they are both 'Fixnum' datatypes.

Comment: By the way, it's the convention in Ruby to use 2-space indent, not 4-space indent.

Comment: `@fib.push(number) #<= this line fails` looks like a typo. It should be `@fib.push(anumber)`.

Comment: Johnsyweb Thanks for pointing that out. The typo only exists on SO, not on my local copy. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: @spuder by the way, I think one of the problems with your original algorithm might be that each recursive call returns an array that represents the additive operands for a Fibonacci number, instead of just the summed Fibonacci number for that sub-sequence. That's just a hunch though, I'm not 100% sure that that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your method:

```
def find_fib(anumber)
  return anumber if anumber <= 1
  (find_fib(anumber - 1) + find_fib(anumber - 2)) # 1
  # ETC...
  @fib.push(number) # 2 and 3
end
```

1. You're calculating a Fibonacci number here, but you don't assign the value to a variable, 
   so you're basically throwing away the number.
2. The last statement evaluated in a Ruby function gets returned, unless you make an 
   explicit `return` statement like in your first line. As [Arie Shaw points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22752528/456814), 
   that last line returns an array object, while the first line returns a number, so you're 
   trying to call `Array + Fixnum`, which is not a defined operation.
3. You're pushing `number` into your `@fib` array, but that variable isn't assigned a
   value anywhere.

If you want a method that generates an array of the first `n` Fibonacci numbers, here's one Ruby way to do it:

```
def fib(n)
  (n == 1) ? [0] : (2..(n-1)).each_with_object([0,1]) { |i,a| a[i] = a[i-2] + a[i-1] }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For the error you posted, that's because the terminate condition of the `find_fib` method returns `anumber`, which is of type `Fixnum`. This return value is used in your former recursion:

```
( find_fib(anumber - 1) + find_fib(anumber - 2 ))
```

Here you are going to call `Array + Fixnum`, which causes the type check error. Change the terminate condition to the following may remove that error.

```
def find_fib(anumber)
  return [anumber] if anumber <= 1
  ...
```

BTW, you `find_fib` won't work as expected, you may need further tweak on the algorithm implementation.

Comment: You are right on both accounts, changing anumber to [anumber] got rid of the error. There still is something wrong with the algorithm that I can look into now. https://gist.github.com/spuder/9885656