# Sum Number String and Integer and Keep the zeroes in the beginning of the string

Tags: ruby

How to sum str and num in Ruby?
And return string again.
In a way to preserve the zeros in the beginning of the string.

**Example:**

```
str = "001"  
num = 3
```

**Expected result:**

```
str + num #=> "004"
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466988/ruby-convert-string-to-integer-or-float . also you could be more clear in the fact that this is ruby in the text of your question.

Comment: I don't agree that it's a duplicate.

Comment: Some context would help. Where do `str` and `num` come from, why do you have to preserve the zeroes, what are you doing with the result?

Comment: For `num = 20`, is the expected result `"021"` or `"0021"`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind modifying `str`, you could do this:

```
3.times { str.next! }
str #=> "004"
```

If you don't want to modify `str`, operate on `str.dup`.

Alternatively:

```
3.times.reduce(str) { |s,_| s.next }
  str #=> "004"
```

which does not mutate `str`.

I know what you're thinking: this isn't very efficient.

Edited to incorporate Stefan's first suggestion. Initially I implemented his second suggestion as well, but I've gone back to `next` and `next!`. I just think `next` reads better than `succ`, and they're clearly methods, so I'm not worried about them being confused with the `next` keyword.

Comment: `3.times { str.next! }` is more concise and I would probably use `succ` to avoid confusion with the `next` keyword.

Comment: Yes, @Stefan: a better way to add by counting on one's fingers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_i` to convert `str` to an integer, add `num` to it, then convert the resulting integer to a string with `to_s`. Zero padding is done using `rjust()`.

```
str = "001"  
num = 3
(str.to_i + num).to_s.rjust(3, '0')
=> "004"
```

Comment: You might want to use `str.size` instead of `3`

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_string(string, number)
    return string.scan(/^0*/)[0]+(string.to_i+number).to_s  
end
puts sum_string("00030", 5)

puts sum_string("00006", 7) 
    returns 000013 which is adding one more zero at the beginning
```

So, this is a slight improvement

```
def sum_string(string, number)
    len = (string.scan(/^0*/)[0]+(string.to_i+number).to_s).length - string.length
    if len > 0 then
        return string.scan(/^0*/)[0][len..-1]+(string.to_i+number).to_s 
    else
        return string.scan(/^0*/)[0]+(string.to_i+number).to_s  
    end
end
```